# How to remove certain views from scrollView view Array swift

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have a paged scrollView and I want to remove the views that are not being shown (or to be animated). I just cant work it out. I want to purge the views that are outside the -1 and +1 views from the shown view so the memory is reduced.

```
func addViewController(vc:UIViewController)->Void{


controllers.append(vc)

// Setup the viewController view

vc.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
scrollview.addSubview(vc.view)

// Constraints

let metricDict = ["w":vc.view.bounds.size.width,"h":vc.view.bounds.size.height]

// - Generic cnst

vc.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view(h)]", options:nil, metrics: metricDict, views: ["view":vc.view]))
vc.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view(w)]", options:nil, metrics: metricDict, views: ["view":vc.view]))
scrollview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[view]|", options:nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view":vc.view,]))

// cnst for position: 1st element

if controllers.count == 1{
  scrollview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[view]", options:nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view":vc.view,]))





  // purge controllers.count > 2 




  // cnst for position: other elements

}else{

  let previousVC = controllers[controllers.count-2]
  let previousView = previousVC.view;



  // purge controllers.count before previousView



  scrollview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[previousView]-0-[view]", options:nil, metrics: nil, views: ["previousView":previousView,"view":vc.view]))

  if let cst = lastViewConstraint{
    scrollview.removeConstraints(cst as [AnyObject])
  }
  lastViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view]-0-|", options:nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view":vc.view])
  scrollview.addConstraints(lastViewConstraint! as [AnyObject])



}
```

Comment: UICollectionView doesn't do what you want ?

Comment: All the views are instantiated at launch. This with over 29 views the memory is hit hard. I am trying to remove the views that are not being animated or shown to reduce the memory (which is massive at the moment).

Comment: "All the views are instantiated at launch" - are you referring to your current `UIScrollView` setup or `UICollectionView` ? UICollectionView is meant to behave kinda like `UITableView` where it reuses cell that are offscreen, hence saving you from that memory issue while at the same time have all the benefits of UIScrollView.

Comment: The present one that presents all the pages next to each other like a pagecontroller.

Comment: You can make the UICollectionView scroll horizontally like a UIScrollView with the paging things. You want me to write an example answer?

Comment: I am using an open source product https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough and wanted to purge the unused views I don't want to make too much work for you.